# Change Axios request network name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using Axios for GET and POST request, and was wondering how to change the network name:

[image: Names for requests]

Now the name is the parameter that gets sent with the request, but I was wondering if I could change the names, so it's clearer what it is for.

Comment: It's request[/response] name, not network name. Network is (just) name of tab that holds request/response data.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get more information is toggling the large request rows.

[image: Large request rows]

Changing the name would involve changing the endpoint path which is most likely not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change your endpoint
`api/v1/:id` has a method message, where you send `id` as a parameter,
google chrome will always show by default the basename of the full path